# What does 'QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED' make problem?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm practicing *Cassini* App by Stanford-for-iOS and this message occurs.

'Cannot convert value of type 'qos_class_t' to expected argument type 'Int'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiL2S.png)

So how should I fix?

Comment: Seems to be code taken from Objective-C (a lot of influence from Objective-C, or rather then old Swift...

Comment: Not tested, but in "Modern" Swift, I guess its equivalent should be `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {}` and `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` for the other one. But what's your Swift version?

Comment: @Larme recently swift version! 5.6. By the way thx for your help!